# IBM PHP instance php buildpack for max number of request

Tags: php, instance, ibm-cloud

I'm using a PHP instance within IBM Bluemix.
Now we are posting raw data from about 200 external devices to a PHP instance.
This rawdata is small (1 or 2 KB), but it sends every 4 to 5 seconds.
If I'm using the standard PHP buildpack, I see that the webpage sometimes won't respond.  (It looks like it is waiting for a free client connection.)

Could anybody tell me which PHP buildpack is the best buildpack for using in PHP instance?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP instance within IBM Bluemix is the opensource cloudfoundry php-buildpack buildpack. You can try the current version of the buildpack to see if your issue is resolved. For example if you would like to use the latest version you can push your app with:

cf push yourAppName -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git

If you need further help please include code examples, logs and anything else that can help with debugging your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problem is related to the used buildpack, you could take a look at [Heroku buildpack: PHP](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php). It uses Composer for dependency management, supports PHP or HHVM (experimental) as runtimes, and offers a choice of Apache2 or Nginx web servers.
You could try this buildpack as an alternative to the default one. I suggest you to test both the web servers to see if you notice different performances with the load spikes.

If the problem persists I think you should do a deeper performance investigation. You could also use one of the services provided by Bluemix in the [DevOps catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/).